# how to connect and create a admin dashboard for listing job offers in db

Tags: python, html, mysql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am currently learning Flask and working on a job offers website. I have connected the job offers to a database. I tried creating an admin dashboard for this, but it's showing a "method not allowed" error. How can I create an admin dashboard to update and view the database?

```py
app.py                                   
@app.route("/admin/jobs")
def show_admin():
    return render_template('admin.html')

@app.route("/adminentry/jobs", methods=["POST"])
def add_job():
    data = request.form
    add_admin_to_db(data)

database.py
def add_admin_to_db(data):
    row = {
        "title": data["title"],
        "location": data["location"],
        "salary": data["salary"],
        "requirement": data["requirement"]
    }
    with engine.connect() as conn:
        query = text("INSERT INTO jobs (title, location, salary, requirement) VALUES (:title, :location, :salary, :requirement)")
        conn.execute(query, row)
        conn.commit()
```

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting?